# Is this web worker code multi-threaded and am I gaining anything

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I have the following web worker code and onMessage handler defined like this

```
var worker = new Worker('worker.js');

worker.addEventListener('message', function(e){
  App.store.loadMany(App.Activity, e.data);
});

worker.postMessage(structure);
```

All my web worker code does in worker.js is invoke the onmessage callback and pass back the passed in objects:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e){ 
  self.postMessage(e.data);
}, false);
```

I am a bit unsure if this code is multithreaded, I am thinking it is not and if I am wondering if I am gaining anything by doing it this way.

Comment: You are not gaining anything that way, but yes it runs in different thread. You can test this by writing infinite loop in your worker and see how the parent script remains responsive

Comment: why am I not gaining anything if it is running in a different thread?  I wanted this loading off the UI thread.

Comment: Is it that the actual loading is being done in the UI thread?  I realise the code in 'worker.js' runs in a different thread but the callback code will run in the UI thread?

Comment: what loading? You are just sending a message that gets sent back. Only the code that is inside the worker.js runs in a different thread. That is, the last snippet. All other snippets run in the main thread. What are you loading anyway? It should be asynchronous.

Comment: I am loading json objects into the ember data store.

Comment: How could I do this asynchronously and thanks for the answers BTW.

Comment: It depends what `App.store.loadMany` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your **Worker** is echoing a message back to the GUI thread which then has to do the work of calling `App.store.loadMany()`. So there is no benefit in this case.

If you change your main GUI thread to:

```
var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
worker.postMessage(structure);
```

and your **worker.js** to:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e){
  App.store.loadMany(App.Activity, e.data);
  self.postMessage('done');
});
```

you will put the work of `App.store.loadMany()` into the **Worker** thread. This is assuming `App.store.loadMany()` can be run in a Worker. There are some restrictions on what a **Worker** can do.

There is a good tutorial [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_web_workers).

Comment: This is the problem I have.  Is there anyway you know of making App.store accessible in both the UI thread and the worker?  At the moment it is created as window.App.

Comment: You could try passing **App** to the worker as a parameter and see if works. I assume you are using **emberjs**. is that correct?